# Converting {"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]]} to geography column using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have a Postgresql table with a text column that has data like the below.

**{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-122.995882414,44.05766941700006],[-122.99818210099994,44.05768878400005]]]}**

I have added a new column to the table with type Geography and I would like to move this multilinestring data to the new geography column.

I need to find the **centroid** of the mulitilinestring in the form of lat/lng so that distance can be calculated from a give address. The table has around 139k rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ST_FromGeoJson`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) to convert the text to a geometry, then you would cast the result to the desired geography format. At last, you can use `ST_Centroid`

ex:

```
select st_AsText(st_geomFromGeoJson('{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-122.995882414,44.05766941700006],[-122.99818210099994,44.05768878400005]]]}'));
                                     st_astext
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 MULTILINESTRING((-122.995882414 44.0576694170001,-122.998182101 44.0576887840001))
```

with the cast:

```
select st_geomFromGeoJson('{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-122.995882414,44.05766941700006],[-122.99818210099994,44.05768878400005]]]}')::geography;
```

... and the centroid

```
select st_centroid(st_geomFromGeoJson('{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-122.995882414,44.05766941700006],[-122.99818210099994,44.05768878400005]]]}')::geography);
```

From a column:

```
SELECT st_centroid(st_geomFromGeoJson(my_geoJson_column)::geography)
FROM myTable;
```

Comment: The only further item to note is that the geography created by this ST_GeomFromGeoJSON example has an SRID of zero.  A geography with a SRID of zero is not very useful so the example should probably use ST_SetSRID to add SRID 4326 to the intermediate geometry conversion before casting it to geography.